# Placing revealed hidden content before HTML spoiler button

Tags: html

Just a few days ago, thanks to Google, I landed [here](http://www.blogolect.com/2014/08/how-to-add-spoiler-or-hideshow-button-in-blogger.html?showComment=1506161312219#c3915676540988380948) and learnt how to make a spoiler in HTML. So the following code works:

```
<div id="spoiler" style="display:none">
ADD YOUR HIDDEN CONTENT HERE
</div>
<button title="Click to Show/Hide Content" type="button" onclick="if(document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display='none'}">Show/Hide</button>
```

But, I would like the spoilered content to appear *under* the button when I reveal it, whereas now it appears *above* the button. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Simply do this :

```html
<button title="Click to Show/Hide Content" type="button" onclick="if(document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display='none'}">Show/Hide</button>
<div id="spoiler" style="display:none">
ADD YOUR HIDDEN CONTENT HERE
</div>
```