# How do I change the style of a button created with HTML

Tags: html

So I am working on a small website on Squarespace.  I have a small HTML code that creates a spoiler button, that shows/hides the content in it after pressing the button.

I got that code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46390304

But it looks extremely ugly on the site, is there any way I can change it's shape and color?

https://prnt.sc/rqchk1

https://prnt.sc/rqciro

Comment: Hi Orion, what you are looking for is called CSS (Cascading StyleSheet). We can't answer you since it all depends on what you're looking for as a look but there are millions of pages on how to learn CSS.

Comment: What looks extremely ugly? The style of the button?

Comment: how do you want it to be changed? You could look here: https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css3_buttons.asp  for styling buttons

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you style html form buttons with css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950238/can-you-style-html-form-buttons-with-css)

Comment: AndrewReese Yes, the style of the button

coderHelper Thank you, I will look into that :D

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't think so.  When putting code in the code block, I have to choose one of the following: https://prnt.sc/rqcqsg

Comment: And? Select CSS, and type the CSS.

Comment: It sounds like you need a guide or tutorial. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS Editor in SquareSpace to add CSS to HTML code.

There are more options in SquareSpace's support articles:

https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545567